# Save RDOMail as eml with type rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822

Tags: outlook-redemption

When saving RDOMail of type rdoBodyFormat.olFormatRichText the embedded pics does not have a content-id. Why is that?

The save operation is within an Outlook add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redemption refers to images created from RTF by the filename, not content id, hence only Content-Location header is set, but not Content-ID.